# How to create a shadow on a Google Maps addCircle method

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I've created a circle on the map using `addCircle` method.

```
        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .strokeWidth(10)
            .radius(radiusLarge)
            .strokeColor(Color.WHITE));
```

Now I have to make a shadow to the circle. How can I do that? I've searched all over the world, but I couldn't found how to make a shadow using `addCircle` method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your best bet would be to add a second circle with a darker color, like Color.GRAY with either a slightly smaller/larger radius or a minor offset in any direction. The mockup I wrote would draw the same circle offset by one in each direction if lat and lng are just integers.

```
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(lat+1, lng+1))
        .strokeWidth(10)
        .radius(radiusLarge)
        .strokeColor(Color.GRAY));
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(lat, lng))
        .strokeWidth(10)
        .radius(radiusLarge)
        .strokeColor(Color.WHITE));
```